# webapi hosted on azure always receives an empty list

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

So here is the scenario. Im sending a list of 14 objects to a webapi hosted on azure. But it always receives an empty list. Im calling the webapi from backend like so.

```
using (HttpClient objHttpCLient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage objMessage = objHttpCLient.PostAsync(new Uri(strUrl), new StringContent(JOContent.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/JSON")).Result;
                    var ResponseClientConfiguration = objMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    sw.WriteLine(objMessage.StatusCode.ToString());
                    if (objMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(ResponseClientConfiguration.Result);
                        objResponse = JObject.Parse(ResponseClientConfiguration.Result);
                        strConfigurationJSON += objResponse["ConfigurationJson"].ToString();
                    }
                }
```

Now this works perfectly when the webapi is hoated on my local environment. it receives all 144 objects, but as soon as it is hosted on azure, it always receives an empty lit.

Comment: Can you share your web-api endpoint signature and also the output of `JOContent.ToString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution. I still dont know why the above doesnt work when the webApi project is hosted on azure but does work when hosted locally or a normal webserver. The workaround is to create a class to coverthe list of objects i.e the list of objects will now be a property of this class.

Before the parameter I was expecting on the webApi was as follows

```
public JObject Validate(List<DateTime> lstDates)
```

After its this

```
public JObject Validate(DateLst objDates)
```

where the DateLst Class structure is as follows

```
public class DateLst 
{

  public List<DateTime> lstDates{ get; set;}

}
```

Now why this works and the former doesnt on azure is still a mystery.